# Stop loop using ng-if condition in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, if-statement

I have this code. `$scope.counter = '1';`

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in catadata">
   <div ng-if="cat.TopCategoryID = 2" >
      <div ng-if="counter = 1" >
         <div class="feedsDisplay" ng-init="counter = counter + 1">
            Creater Img:{{cat.CreatedBy_Profile.Picture.URI}}" 
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to stop loop when `counter = 2`, I want to display just 1 result.

```
ng-init="counter = counter + 1
{{counter}}
```

displaying `11111` it should display `12345`

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do.  Do you really want to display only one element?  And why are you doing equality checks with `=` instead of `==`?

Comment: If you want to display only the result with index 1, just do this `{{ catadata[0].CreatedBy_Profile.Picture.URI }}`

Comment: Do you need quotes around the 1?

Comment: can you provide working sample on jsfiddle or plunkr? and explain want you try to do? not it is unclear

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing with `=` instead of `==`

Try like this

```
ng-if="counter == 1"
```

value of `counter`  is string . add `+` sign before `counter`

try like this

```
ng-init="counter = +counter + 1"
```

Comment: ng-init="counter = counter + 1 
    {{counter}}

displaying 11111 it should display 12345

Comment: @MuhammadRiaz, first `counter` value is _string_ so when you do `+` in just add simbol to string

Comment: like this `counter = +counter + 1`

Answer (score 2):

You cant stop `ng-repeat` conditionally. 
To print only one result you can use

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in catadata | limitTo : 1">
```

OR

```
<div>{{catadata[0]}}</div>
```

Comment: I want limit within ng-if condition  <div ng-if="cat.TopCategoryID = 2" >

Comment: @MuhammadRiaz so add `filter` like `cat in catadata |  filter: {TopCategoryID : 2}`

Comment: @Riaz do it as `<div ng-if="cat.TopCategoryID == 2" >`. But remember ng-repeat will run for all elements of array. `ng-if` will only prevent the element to be created.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than misusing `ng-repeat`, `ng-init` and `ng-if` like this, just try to extract the first matching `cat` before you render it, e.g. in a controller, directive or service:

```
for (var i = 0, maxI = catadata.length; i < maxI; ++i) {
    if (cat.TopCategoryID === 2) {
        $scope.firstMatchingCat = cat;
        break;
    }
}
```

And then in the template:

```
<div class="feedsDisplay">
    Creater Img:{{firstMatchingCat.CreatedBy_Profile.Picture.URI}}" 
</div>
```